# Inserting a row in a mysql table. It doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of new to PHP and I'm trying to build a REST API for an app. For some reason I got stuck at something that should be trivial. **What I want to** do is to be able to insert a new row into the Score-table which is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Scores(
        score_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        item_id INT,
        score DOUBLE UNSIGNED,
        PRIMARY KEY (score_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES Items(internal_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
        );
```

Below is the PHP code I use. The function `setScore` is a member in a class which also has the `db` and `response`-members which you will see. But I have debugged the code enough to see that everything apart form the below function works.

The POST-variables have the correct values and the `sendResponse(200, "SCORE_INSERTED_SUCCESSFULLY")` is executed properly. And I do not try to insert duplicate rows.

**The problem** is that I don't get a new row in the Score-table. However, strangely enough I can see that the primary key is auto incremented each time I try to insert a new row even though no new row appears!

I can insert the row manually by running the exact same query in mysql manually. For example, this works if I run it manually in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO Scores (user_id, item_id, score) VALUES (1,2,6.0);
```

So why does the below not work?

```
function setScore() {       
        if (isset($_POST["user_id"]) && isset($_POST["item_id"]) && isset($_POST["score"]))
            {
                $user = $_POST["user_id"];
                $item = $_POST["item_id"];                
                $score = $_POST["score"];

                $query = 'INSERT INTO Scores (user_id, item_id, score) VALUES (?,?,?)';
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query) or trigger_error($this->db->error."[$query]");
                $stmt->bind_param("iid", $user, $item, $score);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();                
                $this->response->sendResponse(200, "SCORE_INSERTED_SUCCESSFULLY");
                return true;
            }
        $this->response->sendResponse(400, "Invalid request");
        return false;
    }
```

I really appreciate any feedback, this is driving me mad!

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This is the value of the $stmt-variable before execute:

```
mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 3
    [field_count] => 0
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

and after execute:

```
mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 1
    [insert_id] => 30
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 3
    [field_count] => 0
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Why do you always send HTTP 400 back?

Comment: Try and echo the $query variable and copy and paste it into MySQL to see if you get any errors when doing that.

Comment: Also do not use 2 return statements, that is just bad practice... If you use if, then have an else

Comment: @DavidBrossard I only send HTTP 400 back if one or more of the POST-variables where not set.

Comment: @GrumpyToaster As I wrote, I already tried that and it worked!

Comment: @DavidBrossard why is it bad practice to have multiple return statements?

Comment: Can you show the request body you are sending?

Comment: @DavidBrossard completely cannot agree. Else statement for just a return is rather uglier.

Comment: Unless you enabled exceptions, you're simply ASSUMING the query succeeded. You never check return values on the actual `execute()`. A foreign key failure can still kill the query at that point.

Comment: variable scope? how's that `setScore()` function being called?

Comment: @MarcB I tried to do the following: if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$this->db->error, E_USER_WARNING);} but there was no error

Comment: @Fred-ii- probably there's a little framework that calls functions on certain request, as the OP said it's a REST api. It's also maybe a class member function assuming `$this` used there

Comment: @RoyalBg sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by the request body?

Comment: Then maybe your POST arrays are failing. Last ditch effort: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, I added that to the top of all my files but there is still no errors in the error log. The POST variables are correct inside setScore. I printed their values to the error log and they where correct!

Comment: as already stated, echo your query, and start `var_dump()`'ing here and there, to see what's going through or not. I'd like to be of further help, but that's about it for me. I wish you well, *cheers*

Comment: Thanks for your time @Fred-ii-

Comment: Have you tried echoing the stmt error? `echo $stmt->error;`

Comment: Thanks @Zwander but there was no error. In my original post I added the value of $stmt-variable. Not sure if that helps or not!

Comment: The _after_ state of `$stmt` has `[insert_id] => 30`. Does it mean that the record was inserted? Are you looking in the right table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ejay. As I wrote in my original post I can see in my table that the auto incremented primary key is incremented each time I run my code but there is no new rows in my table.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try to insert with different approach like $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

Comment: do you have by any chance `mysqli::autocommit` set to false on `mysqli` connection? Try adding `$this->db->autocommit(true);` after you create the db connection http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php

Comment: @RoyalBg what I meant is have a single return statement e.g. if () {do stuff to x...} else {do stuff to x...} return x

Comment: but here the condition is `if() { do stuff to x and return } else { dont do stuff to x, just return }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have debugged the code enough to see that everything apart form the below function works.

I had to eat my own words this time. It turned out I should have posted the whole class because I had forgot that I set `$this->db->autocommit(FALSE);`. When I commited everything worked as expected!

Thank you for all your comments